# How to join table multiple times to get count of each genre in transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are

TRANSACTION TABLE

```
        transaction_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_id INT,
        inventory_id INT,
        kiosk_id INT,
        rental_out DATETIME,
        rental_proposal INT, 
        rental_due DATETIME,
        rental_cost FLOAT,
        rental_in DATETIME,
        rental_period INT,
        rental_past_due INT,
        late_fee INT
```

INVENTORY TABLE

```
    inventory_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title_id INT,
    title_name VARCHAR(255),
    genre_id INT,
    genre_name VARCHAR(255),
    qty INT
```

I'm trying to figure out a way in order to create a query that allows the inventory_id from the transaction table to create a count of the genre's of each transaction. My query allows to find the number of genres transacted, but only one at a time.

```
SELECT COUNT(genre_id) 
FROM inventory 
INNER JOIN transactions 
ON inventory.title_id = transactions.inventory_id 
WHERE transactions.customer_id = 1 and inventory.genre_id = 1;
```

I'd like to figure out a way to join the table multiple times to display the number of times each genre has been rented, being currently existing genres 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So far, I've come up these queries, but I don't see a logical way to the solution.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.genre_id) as GENRE_A, COUNT(A.genre_id) as GENRE_B, COUNT(A.genre_id) as GENRE_C FROM inventory A 
INNER JOIN transactions D ON A.title_id = D.inventory_id 
INNER JOIN transactions E ON A.title_id = E.inventory_id 
INNER JOIN transactions F ON A.title_id = F.inventory_id 
WHERE A.genre_id = 1 AND A.genre_id = 2 and A.genre_id = 3;

SELECT COUNT(A.inventory_id), COUNT(B.inventory_id), COUNT(C.inventory_id) FROM transactions A, transactions B, transactions C
INNER JOIN inventory D ON A.inventory_id = D.title_id
INNER JOIN inventory E ON A.inventory_id = E.title_id
INNER JOIN inventory F ON A.inventory_id = F.title_id
WHERE A.genre_id = 1 AND B.genre_id = 2 and C.genre_id = 3;
```

I've tried multiple variations, some of which I've deleted and haven't posted, but I can't seem to figure it out. Is there any solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation. 
Only 1 join needed.

This will count the transactions for the 3 genres

```
SELECT
-- trans.customer_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN inv.genre_id = 1 THEN trans.transaction_id END) AS genre1, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN inv.genre_id = 2 THEN trans.transaction_id END) AS genre2, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN inv.genre_id = 3 THEN trans.transaction_id END) AS genre3
FROM transactions trans
JOIN inventory inv ON inv.inventory_id = trans.inventory_id
WHERE inv.genre_id IN (1, 2, 3)
-- GROUP BY trans.customer_id
```

Comment: I understand that this works, but I'm a bit confused as to how, especially the "THEN trans.transaction_id END" part. I'm not sure how it plays into the solution. Is it just declaring any transaction_id? Is it taking all the transaction_id's? Thanks. I just feel it looks a little off logically.

Comment: @hd326 The way this works is that the CASE will only return the transaction_id if the WHEN condition matches, and NULL when it doesn't.  And a COUNT by value doesn't count the NULL's.  Also, you could replace them with a conditional SUM. For example : `SUM(CASE WHEN inv.genre_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS genre1`.   A SUM like this has the advantage that it would still returns 0 if there were no transactions for that genre, while with the COUNT that would return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the results on multiple rows?

```
SELECT genre_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM inventory i INNER JOIN
     transactions t
     ON i.title_id = t.inventory_id 
WHERE t.customer_id = 1 and i.genre_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY genre_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your query, but I got what seems to be a sum of the genres 1, 2, 3 in my transactions. Thanks.

Comment: @hd326 . . . Actually, it should have returned an error.  The query needs the `GROUP BY` that I just added.

Comment: Thank you for answer, that makes the difference, although I didn't expect the GROUP BY clause to separate the query into rows. That's very powerful. Can you explain why that happens, I feel that GROUP BY is a command that should GROUP -- and here it seems like it's adding new rows, kind of weird to me. Thank you!

Comment: @hd326 . . . The query should have failed without the `GROUP BY`.  You must be using an older version of MySQL.  The aggregation function makes this an aggregation query.  Without `group by`, all the data is considered to be in one group.